# Paging view hierarchy broken when dismissing a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, modal-dialog, scroll-paging

I use the SLPagingView (https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingView/) open source library for a paging view based app like Twitter or Tinder.
From some page I open a detail view. When I come back the layout of the paging views is broken.

**DetailViewController.m**

```
- (void)backButtonPressed {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In fact I noticed that the hierarchy of the app is broken just before the DetailView appears.

**SomePageViewController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Perform segue to detailView
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"actionDetail" sender:nil];

   /* Does not work with a modal view controller either
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"bundle:nil];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController =
(DetailViewController *)
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailcontroller_id"];
[self pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];*/
}
```

I got the `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`warning. I tried to replace `self` by `self.navigationController`or `self.parentViewController.navigationController`but both don't work.

Does anyone using this library fix this issue or know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
I modified the SLPagingView library. Add `[self addChildViewController:ctr]` in `initWithNavBarControllers:`, `initWithNavBarItem:` and other life cycle methods.
Check the differences: https://www.diffchecker.com/cnlvslym